# Running Python 3.5.2 Program on Celery 4.0.2 with Rabbitmq

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I am learning how to use Celery to do scheduled python task with Rabbitmq, and come across with problem of making connection. Specifically, I try to learn from an example available on the web (https://github.com/jimmykobe1171/celery-demo/tree/master). The structure and syntax is as below:

Structure:

```
test_celery
    __init__.py
    celery.py
    tasks.py
    run_tasks.py
```

celery.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('test_celery',
             broker='amqp://john:password@localhost/john_vhost',
             backend='rpc://',
             include=['test_celery.tasks'])
```

tasks.py:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from test_celery.celery import app
import time

@app.task
def longtime_add(x, y):
    print ('long time task begins')
    # sleep 5 seconds
    time.sleep(5)
    print ('long time task finished')
    return (x + y)
```

run_tasks.py:

```
from .tasks import longtime_add
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = longtime_add.delay(1,2)
    # at this time, our task is not finished, so it will return False
    print ('Task finished? ', result.ready())
    print ('Task result: ', result.result)
    # sleep 10 seconds to ensure the task has been finished
    time.sleep(10)
    # now the task should be finished and ready method will return True
    print ('Task finished? ', result.ready())
    print ('Task result: ', result.result)
```

Then I run:

```
$ celery -A test_celery worker --loglevel=info
```

Then the server first makes connection but later denied with the following message:

```
 -------------- celery@DOECOMPUTER v4.0.2 (latentcall)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1 2016-12-31 22:04:54
-- * - **** --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         test_celery:0x3d2b828
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://john:**@localhost:5672/john_vhost
- ** ---------- .> results:     rpc://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . test_celery.tasks.longtime_add
...
_winapi.DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS | _winapi.DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access Denied.
```

Could any people advise what happens here? What causes this happened and how to solve it? In fact, I have been struggling with celery for hours and honestly it has been quite a pain on my learning path. Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a login / password problem.

Check your access to Rabbitmq database.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply. I have checked but it works fine. I can use the same user and password to the Rabbitmq web server interface (http://localhost:15672/#/users). Could you suggest any method to further check on the access and connection?

Answer (score 0):

I seem able to resolve this issue by switching Celery 4.0.2 to 3.1.0. Hopefully this version will not have other crash with other applications.